# Visual C++ Class Diagrams

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, visual-c++, uml, diagrams

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and my project is Visual C++. How can I create class diagrams for this? Whenever I try to do it I get the message

> some of the selected types cannot be added to the class diagram. May be due to several limitations of the tool....

I tried *Astah Community* to draw class diagrams manually, then found it has no support for pointers etc.

Comment: You say "Whenever I try to do it..." what is `it`?  Do you mean using the `View Class Diagram` right click option on the project?  Also are you working in a multiple project environment?

Comment: @jmstoker: Yes you are correct. "View Class Diagram" thing. I have no multiple projects.

Comment: Can you create a diagram for a simple project?  Generating class diagrams is a new feature in VS2010 and Microsoft team members have admitted limitations.  It's difficult to narrow down your issue without seeing samples of your code or at least mentioning some of the less common datatypes you may be using that the tool "might" not support.

Comment: @jmstoker: It is using OpenCV library, Microsoft speech engine and other libraries. I am thinking about using Astah community tool stop worrieng about pointers. So 'string *name' will be represented as "string name" in class diagram. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but may be helpful.

From the [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Class Designer does not keep track of the location of source files.
>   Therefore, modifying your project structure or moving source files in
>   a project can cause Class Designer to lose track of the type
>   (especially the source type of a typedef, base classes, or association
>   types). You might receive an error such as Class Designer is unable to
>   display this type. If so, drag the modified or relocated source code to the class diagram 
>   again to redisplay it.